# Node JS) Image upload issue with undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, undefined, multer

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(multer( {dest:'./uploads/',
    onFileUploadStart : function(file){
        console.log('File recieved:');
        console.log(file);
    },
     onFileUploadData:function (file,data){
        console.log('Data recieved');
    },
     onParseEnd: function(req,next){
        next();
     }
}));


app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

app.post('/upload',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.file);
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

It's my core codes for handling uploading image above.

```
    app.post('/upload',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.file);
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

But what I got is 
'undefined
{}'

What's wrong with me?
I'm searching for many questions and most of them said I have to use multer... But the result is the same nothing changes.

My package.json is below:

> {
>     "name": "photozzle",
>     "version": "1.0.0",
>     "dependencies": {
>       "body-parser": "1.14.1",
>       "clear": "*",
>       "express": "3.5.1",
>       "fs": "*",
>       "multer": "^0.1.6",
>       "mysql": "*",
>       "path": "*",
>       "q": "*",
>       "request": "*"
>     },
>     "engines": {
>       "node": "0.10.x",
>       "npm": ">1.4.0"
>     }
>   }

Do you think? Is there anything I'm missing?

I'm using post man to test it.
[image]

Finally, I solved this one thanks to 'Lazarev Alexandr'
The picture below could be proof. 
I wish my question will be helpful for my newbie developers like me. Gracias!
[image]

Comment: How do you send your file to the server? Via a form? Does it have `multipart/form-data` enctype?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I don't know actuallly the meaning of 'multipart/form-data'? so that could be the answer... what is that...?

Comment: How do you send your data to the server? From an html form?

Comment: I'm using Post man Body-Binary-.PNG @LazarevAlexandr

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Your answer was not helpful as you know... but you just do the lolly

Comment: See the documentation before you shouting on other .https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Be polite, I already tried to read it but hard for newbie to understand so I'm searching for SO, is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer):

> NOTE: Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).

So, if you want to use `multer` you should not send the image as a binary stream. You should use multipart form request instead. Here is how you can achieve it with Postman tool:

[image]

Also, I would suggest you to use the latest version of the `multer`. Update it by running this command in terminal:

```
npm install multer@latest
```

Afterwards, remove `bodyParser` middleware usage, and use `multer` itself. Your code should look like:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({dest:'./uploads/'});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

app.post('/upload', upload.single('img'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: If request is successful, is that image file stored at server automatically? but it's different from what I know "www.domain.com/test.png" but mine is "uploads/dsanfjkdlsaf"

Comment: Read the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer. There is described how you can change filename.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't make it brother, I renew one at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135320/how-can-i-set-uploaded-file-name would you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm little busy now, but I will take a look when I'll be free.

Comment: Yes I understand, thank you for saying that as you told me I read docs again and again ... sorry for my stupidness