# How can I set uploaded file name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

By using 'multer' , I made it to request image file like this.
[image]

And this file is stored at 'uploads' folder I set.
my code is below:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({dest:'./uploads/'});
//var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.post('/upload', upload.single('puzzle'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

But I want to set my file name like 'abc.png' not 'abc'

I read docs and what I found is that

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

So my modified code is below:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(file.filename+'.png', file);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.post('/upload', upload.single('puzzle'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

But in this case, the error occurs and says 'Error: ENOENT, open '/uploads/puzzle-1449496743377' , not like the picture above...

How could I solve this?

I'm sure many newbie developers like me will have in trouble thanks to unkind docs...

Answer (score 1):

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer')
//var uploader = multer({dest:'./uploads/'});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.png');
    });
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.post('/upload', upload.single('puzzle'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

Solved, thank you all guys thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the definition of the destination dir. The starting '.' is missing.
Try to use this code:

```
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, './uploads/');
},
```